Biblatex inline citations unintentionally bold?
For some reason all my inline citations using biblatex are bold independently of the style selected without redefining any citation commands. See below

(The example above was created using \paramcite without manualy selecting a style. I.e. using \usepackage[]{biblatex}.
In my understanding these shouldn't be bold using the default configuration but in a regular font.
How can I fix this? (Ideally without manually overriding the \cite or \paramcite command)
Additional context:
biblatex 2018/11/02 v3.12
biber version: 2.12
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)

This looks like no or a failed biber compilation (Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number). Have you run biber? Can you try running biber on the command line? Does that give any errors?

Upon calling biber ms.bcf it runs without error but it throws a lot of warnings regarding case mismatches. I'll fix these and keep you posted

You were right.
These aren't "citations" but rather errors warnings for unmatched labels.
I wasn't familiar with that kind of output after switching from bibtex to biblatex.
Feel free to write a proper reply so I can mark this question as  answered.
